# Qt-based software localization: Reusing unique strings across contexts?

Tags: c++, qt, localization, internationalization, translation

I understand that I can use comments to disambiguate similar strings defined in the same context [[1](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/i18n-source-translation.html#disambiguation)].

But is it possible to reuse the same string defined in different contexts?  The motivation is to reduce the workload on translators.  For exameple, I have "New Figure" defined in main-window.cc:

```
_new_figure_action = new_menu->addAction (tr ("New Figure"));
```

and also in shortcut-manager.cc:

```
init (tr ("New Figure"), "main_file:new_figure", QKeySequence ());
```

In this case, using tr()'s second input argument wouldn't help, I think:

```
_new_figure_action = new_menu->addAction (tr ("New Figure", "same_context"));
init (tr ("New Figure", "same_context"), "main_file:new_figure", QKeySequence ());
```

I'm not interested in manually reusing translation strings in Qt Linguist [[2](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linguist-translators.html#reusing-translations)].

Maybe there's some metadata that I can add to strings and make them unique? [[3](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/i18n-source-translation.html#adding-meta-data-to-strings)]

Comment: But you understand that translation may differ based on context, right? In Polish for example the same text on a button and in a window title has to be translated in different mode...

Comment: Sure, although in this case, the implied context is exactly the same: it's keyboard shortcuts for menu entries.